# Finding NULL in a vector

Tags: c++, stl

I'd like to find out if a vector of pointers contains an entry that is NULL, preferably using code in the STL and not writing a loop. I've tried this expression:

```
std::find(dependent_events.begin(), dependent_events.end(), NULL)
```

But I get errors telling me that I have a "comparison between a pointer and an integer." Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What type (exactly) is `dependent_events`?

Comment: Why not just write your own routine that loops through the vector either until it hits a null or until it reaches the end?

Comment: @MGZero Because why bother? C++ already provides an appropriate function.

Comment: NULL is usually a #define 0. Not actually a pointer. This causes many issues. The new C++11 (or C++0x) addresses this issue by introducing the 'nullptr' keyword, which is a null pointer of type **void***

Comment: @MGZero: because it's usually a bad idea to reinvent the wheel. The standard library offers the tools to solve this problem. Why not use it?

Comment: @EddieBytes: no it isn't. :) `nullptr` is of type `nullptr_t`, and is implicitly convertible to any pointer type, but it is a unique type, not `void*`.

Comment: @EddieBytes - in fact it's explicitly forbidden from being `void*`

Comment: And just to give you a headache, `nullptr_t` (the type of `nullptr`)  is defined in the standard as `decltype(nullptr)`: in other words, it's defined to be "the type of nullptr".  :)

Comment: @Platinum Azure, It's a vector<Foo*> where Foo is some class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NULL` in C++ is just an integer constant. The pointer conversion is implicit in appropriate contexts, but this isn’t one. You need to cast explicitly:

```
std::find(dependent_events.begin(), dependent_events.end(), static_cast<P>(0));
```

Where `P` is the appropriate type of the pointers in the collection. Alternatively, Eddie has correctly pointed out the C++11 solution which should work in modern compilers (if C++11 has been enabled).

---

The reason that plain `NULL` doesn’t work is the following: C++ forbids implicit conversion of an integer to a pointer. There is one exception only, a *literal value* `0` is treated as a null pointer in initialisations and assignments to pointers (literal `0` acts as the “null pointer constant”, §4.10), and `NULL` is just `0` (§18.1.4).

But when used in a template instantiation (such as in the above call to `find`), C++ needs to infer a template type for each of its parameters and the type inferred for `0` is *always the same*: `int`. So `find` is called with an `int` argument (which, inside the function, is no longer a *literal*) and as mentioned above, there is no implicit conversion between `int` and a pointer.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there an error here that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @jalf: I suppose technically, if we are looking for `NULL`, `T` must already be a pointer type and adding the extra `*` could be wrong (if the user doesn't figure that out). But that's not nearly enough to deserve a -1...

Comment: Misinformed people are also allowed to vote. I've noticed that both on SO and in general.  ;-)

Comment: @Platinum: that's assuming that `T` is the type we're looking for. Nothing in the code says that is the case. :) The function might just as well be looking through a vector of `T*`.

Comment: @Platium `T` is the “appropriate type” ;-) So my answer is right by definition. But I agree that it’s murky, I’ll change that.

Comment: @jalf: Well, nothing in the code says that, but people do tend to think of `std::vector<T>` and if they (erroneously) equate the `T`s, there is room for confusion. I wasn't criticizing the answer-- I didn't downvote and I have no problem with it. I was only speculating on the downvote.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Yes, I understand that, but your downvoter seemed not to.

Comment: @Konrad:  This is a good answer, but it would be a _great_ answer if you added some text explaining why the compiler is unable to perform the conversion automatically in this case.

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
std::find(dependent_events.begin(), dependent_events.end(), nullptr)
```

This is assuming you are using the new c++11 standard.

Like I said in the comment above, NULL is actually a #define NULL 0, an integer to be more precise.

If not using c++11, try:

```
std::find(dependent_events.begin(), dependent_events.end(), static_cast<void*>(NULL));
```

Comment: He doesn't really say that he is using C++11 in his question and I think it's still too early to assume everyone is automatically using it.

Comment: @Platinum Azure, you are definitely right, I have edited the answer to make sure it matches his needs.

Comment: @jalf: It's correct, but it only helps if the questioner is using C++11. I'm trying to help improve the answer. Notice that I didn't downvote it; this is because it had no misinformation. It's even better now.

Comment: @EddieBytes: Thanks for working with me to try to make the community a better place. +1 for you :-)

Comment: @Platinum: I know, I didn't mean to imply otherwise. :)

Comment: This is a good answer, and I look forward to using C++11! Unfortunately, we are not currently using it at work...

Answer (score 2):

Just cast `NULL` as a pointer.  In C++, `NULL` is just an integer constant.

```
std::find(dependent_events.begin(), dependent_events.end(), (int *)NULL);
```

Obviously substitute whatever type of data the vector is holding for `int *`

Comment: You won't get votes from me if you're using c-style casts without a *good* reason.

Comment: @awoodland: I have no good reason (unless you count habit). One of the advantages of not being a professionaly programmer is that I don't have to follow all the conventions when I don't feel like it, and static_cast<int *> is a lot to write :)

Comment: @Daniel Just remember that good habits can save you a lot of debugging headaches. Using C++ casts will do extra safety checking and make you think twice about why you're doing it.

Comment: It's not much more to write (and my editor normally finishes it for me anyway) but it *will* avert some enormous headaches by being in that habit.

Comment: @awoodland: I guarantee that you are correct. I'm just hoping it doesn't happen for a while.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't want to go into an argument about what you should write, but `static_cast<int>` is intentionally a lot to write. It is a cast, and casts *should* be ugly. It also makes them easier to find when searching in the code. Oh, and it's safer (the C-style cast can do several very different things depending on context, so if you change the surrounding code, your C-style cast might suddenly, without warning, do something completely different (and wrong))

Comment: And an implicit conversion is even safer than a `static_cast`.  So prefer `{ int* needle = NULL; std::find(dependent_events.begin(), dependent_events.end(), needle); }` instead of any cast.